# Get only part of a text file

Tags: vb.net

I am building a VB Parser and I have to parse VB classes as file.

Right now I'm proceeding like this:

```
Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList()
```

Where `fileName` is the actual path of the vb class file to parse. However my main concern is that it actually get ALL the lines in the files.

So say that I have a vb.class that looks like this:

```
Public Class Class1VB


    Friend item1 As String
    Friend item2 As String
    Friend item3 As String
    Friend item4 As String
    Friend item5 As String
    Friend item6 As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.new()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub InstanciateVariables()

        item1 = New String()
        item2 = New String()
        item3 = New String()
        item4 = New String()
        item5 = New String()
        item6 = New String()

    End Sub

End Class

#End Region
```

And I only want the item located in the `InstanciateVariables()` Sub in the `lines` array, is there a way to do that using `Linq` or any VB logic available?

Comment: You declare the varibles as `String` but initialize them as an array of strings? Anyway, you should initialize your List, using the `New` keyword. But where is your problem?

Comment: Well I get the whole document in the list and the point of my question is if there's a way to only get the sub I'm looking for.

Comment: Do all the code files have the flag that says "InstanceVariables" or was that just a for-example?

Comment: That's an example, but it is safe to assume that every file will always contain the "InstanceVariables" flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `File.ReadLines()`, instead of `File.ReadAllLines()`, you get an `IEnumerable(Of String)` which you can use Linq to query, while reading the minimum number of lines required.  e.g. This would get the *contents* of `InstanciateVariables`, without the `Sub` and `End Sub` lines, and would only read up to the `End Sub` line.

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(fileName)
Dim selectedLines = lines.
    SkipWhile(Function(x) Not x.Contains("InstanciateVariables()")).
    Skip(1).
    TakeWhile(Function(x) Not x.Contains("End Sub"))
For Each l In selectedLines
    Console.WriteLine(l)
Next
```

It still has to read all the lines before the `Public Overrides Sub InstanciateVariables()` line - I don't know of any way to avoid that.

If you want the `Sub` and `End Sub` lines it's a little more tricky, but you could create an extension method to take lines inclusively:

```
<Extension>
Public Iterator Function TakeUntilInclusive(Of T)(data As IEnumerable(Of T), predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For Each item In data
        Yield item
        If predicate(item) Then
            Return
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And then use that:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines(fileName)
Dim selectedLines = lines.
    SkipWhile(Function(x) Not x.Contains("InstanciateVariables()")).
    TakeUntilInclusive(Function(x) x.Contains("End Sub"))
For Each l In selectedLines
    Console.WriteLine(l)
Next
```

Comment: Nope, getting the `Sub` and `End Sub` values was not necessary. You got exactly the point I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How long are your files? If they are not huge, you could load the contents of the entire file into a single string and then use String.IndexOf() to identify the location within the string where the "InstanciateVariables()" code appears.  Next,locate the subsequent location where the "End sub" appears and then perform A string.substring() operation to pull out the desired contents.

Comment: The length of the files vary, depending on the class to parse. The structure however remains the same and, as mentioned above, it will always contain a "InstantiateVariables" sub which is the target required.

Comment: They are probably not bigger than the maximum size of a string (which, from what I understand, is quite large).  Give it a shot and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could 1) get the whole list into ListOfAllLines, 2) in a loop, read each line one by one until you get to the one that says "InstanceVariables", 3) in a loop, copy from ListOfAllLines into ListOfImportantLines until you get to "End Sub", 4) stop reading ListOfAllLines and delete it.